# Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable attempting to append item to a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a function that returns a new array consisting of elements which are multiple of their own index in input array (length > 1).

Here's an example: `[22, -6, 32, 82, 9, 25]` → `[-6, 32, 25]`

I wrote this code but `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` is occurring. How can I solve my problem?

```
def multiple_of_index(arr):
    i = 1
    i_of_arr= len(arr)
    res_arr = []
    for i in range(1,i_of_arr):
        if arr[i] % i == 0:
            res_arr.extend(arr[i])
    return res_arr
```

Comment: Only use `res_arr.extend(...)` when you want to append the items of a **list**. Otherwise, use `res_arr.append(...)`. The `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` comes from the fact that the `extend` method tried to *iterate* the elements of something it can iterate, but it got an `int` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a list to `extend`, or you can use `append` since you are just appending a single item at a time.

```py
def multiple_of_index(arr):
    i = 1
    i_of_arr= len(arr)
    res_arr = []
    for i in range(1,i_of_arr):
        if arr[i] % i == 0:
            res_arr.extend([arr[i]]) # list containing arr[i]
    return res_arr
```